# GXT Grid row is not selectable

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I'm new to GWT. I've a grid which has simple data mapped from a BaseModel. When the user selects a row, it is supposed to be selected. I've checked a few examples and post, it seems that we are doing it correctly. Code below to create the grid.

Could you please mention the senarios in which this selection will be blocked?

```
    List<BaseModel> gridData= new ArrayList<BaseModel>();
    List<ColumnConfig> config = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();
    config.add(new ColumnConfig("isPrimary","Primary",70));
    config.add(new ColumnConfig("accountName","Account Name",320));
    config.add(new ColumnConfig("activeProgram","Active Program",150));
    config.add(new ColumnConfig("accountNumber","Account",100));
    config.add(new ColumnConfig("accountXref","Account Xref",150));
    config.add(new ColumnConfig("status","Status",93));

    ColumnModel cm = new ColumnModel(config);

    PagingModelMemoryProxy proxy = new PagingModelMemoryProxy(gridData);
    final PagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<Data>> loader = new BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<Data>>(proxy);

    loader.setRemoteSort(false);
    store = new GroupingStore<Data>(loader);
    final PagingToolBar toolBar = new PagingToolBar(10);
    toolBar.bind(loader);
    loader.load(0, 10);

    GroupingView view = new GroupingView();
    view.setShowGroupedColumn(true);
    view.setForceFit(true);
    view.setGroupRenderer(new GridGroupRenderer() {
        public String render(GroupColumnData data) {
            String l = data.models.size() == 1 ? "Item" : "Items";
            return data.group.substring(data.group.indexOf("|") + 1, data.group.length())
                    + " (" + data.models.size() + " " + l + ")";
        }
    });

    ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
    cp.setBodyBorder(false);

    cp.setButtonAlign(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cp.setLayout(new FitLayout());
    cp.setFrame(true);
    cp.setSize(verticalPanelWidth, "300px");
    cp.setBorders(hidden);
    cp.setBottomComponent(toolBar);
    GWT.log("store size" + store.getCount());
    grid = new Grid<Data>(store,cm);
    final GridSelectionModel<Data> sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
    sm.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    grid.setSelectionModel(sm);

    final CellSelectionModel<Data> csm = new CellSelectionModel<Data>();
    csm.bindGrid(grid);

    grid.setBorders(true);
    grid.ensureDebugId("gridDebugId");
    //grid.ensureDebugId("gridDebugId");
    grid.setTabIndex(5);
    cp.add(grid);
    return cp;
```

Comment: If you want rows to be selected, why is a CellSelectionModel configured to be used instead?

Comment: I was trying something, trying to get it to work, that may not be breaking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not even the answer which i gave previously, it is the CSS!!!!!

I'm using GXT lib for the GWT , they have gxt-all.css file and in this file ,they have

.x-grid3-row-over class declared at a couple of places, this helps to define the row color of the grid. I've removed the background image and the color properties in there, it started working as it is supposed to work. All this time, the background image is being shown when I mouse over.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why it worked, but i've made the grid declaration and instantiation inside the function itself, after setting up all the properties on the grid object i've assigned it to the member variable. this worked without any problem. See below code snippet.

```
**Grid<Data> grid = new Grid<Data>(store,cm);**
final GridSelectionModel<Data> sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
sm.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
grid.setSelectionModel(sm);

final CellSelectionModel<Data> csm = new CellSelectionModel<Data>();
csm.bindGrid(grid);

grid.setBorders(true);
grid.ensureDebugId("gridDebugId");
//grid.ensureDebugId("gridDebugId");
grid.setTabIndex(5);
**globalGrid = grid;**
cp.add(grid);
return cp;
```

Comment: You should still remove that second selection model if you aren't using it, as that other selection model is bound to the grid and will try to handle events if able.