# Change row mouseover color of the GWT Grid when selected

Tags: gwt, gxt

When a button is pressed, i change the background of a few rows in a Grid component, I've achieved it so far, but, when the user mouses over the selected row, it does not show the color that is set, how to change the color of the mouse over item to match the selected item color? Code here so far.

```
for(int i=0;i<grid.getStore().getCount();i++){
    Element row = (Element) grid.getView().getRow(i);
    row.getStyle().setProperty("backgroundColor", "#FFFFFF");
}
for(int item:items){
    Element row = (Element) grid.getView().getRow(item);
    row.getStyle().setProperty("backgroundColor", "#DFE8F6");
}
```

Changed as per the answer.

```
for(int i=0;i<grid.getStore().getCount();i++){
    Element row = (Element) grid.getView().getRow(i);
    row.getStyle().setProperty("backgroundColor", "#FFFFFF");
    row.removeClassName("ps-grid-selected-row");                    
}
Element row = (Element) grid.getView().getRow(indexItem);
row.getStyle().setProperty("backgroundColor", "#DFE8F6");
//              row.getStyle().setProperty("hover", "#DFE8F6");
row.addClassName("ps-grid-selected-row");
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add a mouse over color to the row is through CSS.  In your CSS file, add an entry like this:

```
.selected-row:hover {
  background-color: #DFE8F6;
}
```

And back in your code, instead of setting the background color just add the CSS class:

```
for(int i=0;i<grid.getStore().getCount();i++){
  Element row = (Element) grid.getView().getRow(i);
  row.removeClassName( "selected-row" );
}
for(int item:items){
  Element row = (Element) grid.getView().getRow(item);
  row.addClassName( "selected-row" );
}
```

When you select the row, just add the `selected-row` classname and when it's not selected just remove the classname.  The CSS specifies that when the user hovers over the class `selected-row`, it will use the #DFE8F6 background color.

Comment: But, No where in the code i mention that the row is selected. I just change the background color.

Comment: So when you press the button, you set the background color of a few rows - we're calling these rows selected, right?  And when you hover over the row it's not displaying the #DFE8F6 color?

Comment: I've modified the question, based on your solution, but, it does not seems to solve the issue, it still shows the mouse over of un selected item

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366934/gxt-grid-row-is-not-selectable found the solution.

Comment: Keep in mind to reload your CSS file in the browser. Often it is cached a long time and your changes will not appear!